# Why is the default PHP time zone "Europe/Moscow" in my system?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, timezone

I have been running PHP on many Ubuntu versions and all of them exhibit the same "feature". When I dump the output of the `phpinfo()` function to a web page, I see the following:

```
Default timezone:   Europe/Moscow
```

when both `php.ini` files (`/etc/php/7.?/apache2/php.ini` and `/etc/php/7.?/cli/php.ini`) have the `date.timezone` setting commented out, as it is the case by default.

My system's time zone has always been set correctly to `Europe/Istanbul`:

```
$ file /etc/localtime
/etc/localtime: symbolic link to /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Istanbul
```

However, PHP thinks my local time zone is `Europe/Moscow` instead. Currently, these two time zones are similar, but this was not so in the past and may not be so in the future.

To solve, this problem each time these `php.ini` files are being updated (for example, after a patch or system upgrade) I have to manually edit them and set:

```
date.timezone = Europe/Istanbul
```

What is the reason of this strange behavior and what can I do to solve this problem?

Currently, I am on Ubuntu 19.10 with PHP 7.3, but the problem exists in previous OS and PHP versions too.

Answer (score 0):

You said yourself that Moscow and Istanbul are in the same timezone. If you are worried that your PHP programs may suffer functionality in the event that this were to ever change you can may use the function

`date_default_timezone_set ( string $timezone_identifier ) : bool`

to override the php.ini file. I have included a [link](https://www.php.net/date_default_timezone_set) to the documentation.

Comment: I do not want to put any code in my PHP code. The `php.ini` file is the correct way to set ***system-wide*** my time zone. The problem is that the default php.ini file is somehow "set" to Moscow time zone. (Instead it should be "set" to Istanbul time zone, which is my system-level set time zone.)